# div won't display on image hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, tooltip

can't figure out why my div won't display on this hover any help is appreciated.

```
$('a[rel=tooltipimage]').bind('mouseover',function(e){
e=e?e:window.event;
$('#tooltip').css({
position:'absolute',
top:e.pageY,
left:e.pageX
});
})
```

HTML:

```
</span>
<a href="#" class="tooltipimage"><img src="/applications/images/icons/info_icon.gif"/></a>
</span> 
<div class="tooltip" style="margin:0 0 0 18px; display:none;">
<b>tooltip text goes here</b><br />                                                                 
 </div>
```

all i'm trying to do is display that div floating next to the image when they mouseover and disappear when they leave.  I have jquery installed and everything but don't want to put in a bunch of addons and stuff when all i need is the most simple of tooltips.  if only i wasnt in classic asp i could use a modalpopup but unfortunately no luck.

Thanks in advance,
NickG

Comment: Your example has no `a` element with a `rel` attribute. It has one with a class though.

Comment: You have two closing span tags

Comment: thank you everyone for all of your help and in pointing out my flaws as a JS guy because I know that is not my bag, i decided to go the straight CSS route because it was quickest and easiest but everything provided was very helpful, thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change some of your html, you do not have to use javascript (unless the positioning has to be dynamic. Then you can set that using javascript). You can do it with plain css. If you just want a small text, you can always use the [title](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp) attribute

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/P3ZUt/1/)

```
<span class="tooltipimage">
    <a href="#"><img src="/applications/images/icons/info_icon.gif"/></a>
    <label>tooltip text goes here</label>
</span> 


.tooltipimage:hover label{
    display:block;
}

.tooltipimage label{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:20px;
}

.tooltipimage{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs to be like this

```
$('a.tooltipimage').bind('mouseover',function(e){
e=e?e:window.event;
$('.tooltip').css({
position:'absolute',
top:e.pageY,
left:e.pageX
});
})
```

Since tooltip is a class not an ID

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors are wrong. It should be

```
$('a.tooltipimage').bind('mouseover',function(e){
    e = e ? e : window.event;
    $('.tooltip').css({
        position:'absolute',
        top:e.pageY,
        left:e.pageX,
        display: 'block'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several errors. Try this:

```
$('a.tooltipimage').hover(function (e) {
    e = e ? e : window.event;
    $('.tooltip').show().css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: e.pageY,
        left: e.pageX
    })
}, function () {
    $('.tooltip').hide()
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZBUB9/1)**

- You were selecting `a[rel=tooltipimage]` which doesn't exist, but `a.tooltipimage` does.
- You were also selecting `#tooltip` which doesn't exist, but `.tooltip` does.
- `.bind()` was deprecated in favor of `.on()` as of 1.7
- Your opening span tag is incorrect but I imagine that's just a typo.
- Since you wanted to hide the tooltip as well, I used `.hover()` to hide the tooltip on mouseleave.

Answer (score 1):

Your a tag does not have an attribute rel which is equal to *tooltipimage*. However it has a class named tooltipimage. Also you were hiding the tooltip but never displaying it again.

The following should do the trick:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P3ZUt/)**

```
$('a.tooltipimage').bind('mouseover',function(e){
    e=e?e:window.event;
    $('.tooltip').css({
        display: 'block',
        position:'absolute',
        top:e.pageY,
        left:e.pageX
    });
})
```

A minor error in your html is that, you have 2 closing span tags but no starting ones.

Comment: sorry about that it is for another span that it is encased in just didn't think all of the preceding html was necessary, im going to try this out and let you know, thanks for the help! and that goes for everyone, thank you guys for such a quick and helpful response

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code, your first `span` is closing, not opening, you are using the wrong selector for the *anchor*, and you are using an *id* selector instead of a *class* selector for the *div*. After you apply all of the *css* to your *div* you've got to show it.

**Markup**:

```
<span>
<a href="#" class="tooltipimage"><img src="/applications/images/icons/info_icon.gif"/></a>
</span> 
<div class="tooltip" style="margin:0 0 0 18px; display:none;">
<b>tooltip text goes here</b><br />                                                                 
 </div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('.tooltipimage').on('mouseover',function(e)
{
    e=e?e:window.event;
    $('.tooltip').css(
    {
        position:'absolute',
        top:e.pageY,
        left:e.pageX
    }).show();
}).on("mouseout",function(){$('.tooltip').hide()});
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/vgYeR/

I also bound the **mouseout** event so that it looks more like a tooltip.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('a[rel="tooltipimage"]')
```

I think you need the quotes.